# How can I access HTML elements by (missing) ID in protractor when running on android?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, protractor, ionic4

I am running protractor on an ionic (4) angular (7) app that is able to run tests using appium.

The test I have work fine when it tries to locate elements by CSS but fails when locating by ID.

I get

```
 NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="login-button"])
```

However the test runs fine on browser without cordova/android but I noticed all IDs are missing in the HTML of the cordova/android app

[image]

which are fine in the browser (non app) note: `id="login-button"`

[image]

I've tried adding

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(button), 10000)
```

but then the browser waits forever.

For Example in my HTML

```
<ion-button id="login-button" class="login-btn" (click)="login()">LOGIN</ion-button>
```

Then in the test

```
const button = await element(by.id('login-button'))
button.click();
```

I expect the test to click on the button and continue to the next page but the test fails on android only.

I need to be able to search/locate by IDs because sometimes I dynamically generate IDs based on `ngFor` etc. It can locate all other elements by CSS just not by ID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you can still locate them by their class

`element(by.css('.login-btn.md.button.button-solid.ion-activatable.ion-focusable.hydrated'));`

Or with buttonText?

`element(by.buttonText("LOGIN"));`

Comment: Agreed - however a lot of other buttons and components are dynamically generated in `ngFor` ,for example, or using the ids returned by the data model or REST call so I'm just wondering why this works in browser and not on app. It helps target the test to specific buttons and components easier by using `id`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read about `await` keyword, how to use it, and then try

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(button), 10000)

const button = element(by.id('login-button'))
await button.click();
```

Then if doesn't work, ping me, we'll try something else